# TextView doesn't show full text after setting dialog background to transparent

Tags: android, dialog, textview, full-text-search, transparent

I'm creating a custom dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(cont);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_error_layout);
...
```

and I'm setting a transparent background for its window in this dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

if I do that, the TextView included in *dialog_error_layout* doesn't show full text.
It shows about the 80% of the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_error_background"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/dialog_content_padding" >

...

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/dialog_error_content_text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_error_content_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?
Thanks for all good answers!

Comment: I think you should use android:layout_width="fill_parent" for linear layout

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is good  to get the width and height of android device screen (whatever its size) By:

```
//Define the size of layout 
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int widths = display.getWidth();  
int heights = display.getHeight();
```

Then you can specify the width or height based on these values! As:

```
yourTextview.setLayout(widths ,
                   heights );
```

hope this helpful ,,,